# I'am receiving a json array from server, how to map this array with angular 2 formarray

Tags: json, angular

my recieving json array looks something like this

```
questions = [
{
q_name="question 1",
op_1="op 1",
op_2="op 2",
answer=1
},
{
q_name="question 2",
op_1="op 1",
op_2="op 2",
answer=2
}
];
```

i want to display this data in a form with radio buttons to choose options
how to achieve this, im new to angular 2

Comment: can you post required html, so have better visualization

Comment: export class QuestionList 
{
    public q_name:string;
    public ch_one:string;
    public ch_two:string;
    public ch_three:string;
    public ch_four:string;
    public answer:number;
  }                                                                                                                 this is the model object and i'am receiving an object of type QuestionList[].       now how to display the data inside the object with radio buttons for user to choose an option for each question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your Question collection object in **component** as below.

```
//Define private variable
questions: any;

//List of questions
this.questions = [
{
    "q_name":"question 1",
    "op_1":"op 1",
    "op_2":"op 2",
    "answer":"op 1"
},
{
    "q_name":"question 2",
    "op_1":"op 3",
    "op_2":"op 4",
    "answer":"op 4"
}
];
```

Now, In **HTML** render radio button as below:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions;let i=index">
<div>
    Question : {{question.q_name}}
</div>    
<div>
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="question.answer" name="{{i}}" value="question.op_1">{{question.op_1}}<br />
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="question.answer" name="{{i}}" value="question.op_2">{{question.op_2}}<br />
</div>
```